# What is the dimension of $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices with elements from $\mathbb{C}$, the elements are of the form $a_{ij}+\iota b_{ij} $. It seems the dimension of $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $2n^2$ since there are $2n\times n$ real numbers in the matrix.

But consider the space of all endomorphisms on $\mathbb{C} ^n$ denoted by $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{C} ^n)$ which has dimension of $2n \times 2n = 4n^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and it is isomorphic to $M(n,\mathbb{C})$. This gives dimension of $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ to be $4n^2$.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Well... do you think a complex matrix acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and produces a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$, or do you think a complex matrix acts on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and produces a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$. In that distinction lies your factor two.

Comment: You get $4n^2$ only when you look at $\mathrm{End}_{\Bbb{R}}(\Bbb{C}^n)$. The dimension of $\mathrm{End}_{\Bbb{C}}(\Bbb{C}^n)\simeq M(n,\Bbb{C})$ over $\Bbb{R}$ is twice its dimension over $\Bbb{C}$, see Andrea Mori's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that $\mathrm{End}_{\Bbb C} (\Bbb C^n)$ is not isomorphic to $M(n, \Bbb C)$ *over* $\Bbb R$ (only over $\Bbb C$).

The first result $2n^2$ is the valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Given any finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb C$ one has
$$
\dim_{\Bbb R}V=2\dim_{\Bbb C}V.
$$
If $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis over $\Bbb{C}$ then$\{v_1,iv_1...,v_n,iv_n\}$ is a basis over $\Bbb{R}$.